# Collider not working issue while decreasing player health

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics, collision

when the zombie goes in attacking state the health start decreasing i want to change the code to that when it collides to my FPS the health goes down.

```c#
if (anim.GetBool("isAttacking") && !anim.GetBool("isWalking"))
{
    PlayerHealthBar.value -= 2;
    Debug.Log("Hit");
    //anim.SetBool("isAttacking", false);

}
```

for Collide i used collider scirpt which is this.....

```c#
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        health = health - 20f;
        Debug.Log("hit");
    }
}
```

But its also not working what should i do now.

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 0):

Try `OnCollisionEnter` instead `OnTriggerEnter`. I have noticed that these two functions are a little unpredictable as to which one works at any given time. I usually have a function of each of these methods and one or the other is always hit.

`OnCollisionEnter` is very similar to `OnTriggerEnter`. Here is the change you would have to make:

```c#
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision other)
{
    if(other.gameobject.tag == "Enemy")
   {
        health = health - 20f;
        Debug.Log("hit");
    }
}
```

To be clear this will only decrement the health variable. If this was supposed to be the health variable on the zombie, you may have to change your code a bit.

You may also have to change health to `PlayerHealthBar.value` depending on where this script is located and the value you actually want to see changed. I trust that you understand enough about code to know if this is necessary or not.

Lastly make sure both objects have a collider and rigidbody.

Comment: *`I have noticed that these two functions are a little unpredictable as to which one works at any given time.`* Uh, its entirely dependent on [a single value](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html)...